# Portable Crop Image Activity for Xamarin.Android (Monodroid / Mono for Android)

Tags: image, android-activity, android-camera, crop, xamarin

I am looking for a portable crop image activity to use inside my `Xamarin.Android` application. Something similar to this one written in Java: https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage.

I think this is necessary for those Android devices which do not have the default `com.android.camera.action.CROP` intent action implemented.

```
try {
    // Call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not support it).
    Intent cropIntent = new Intent ("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    ...
    Activity.StartActivityForResult(cropIntent, ...);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    // Call a custom portable crop image activity here.
}
```

Finally, are there any open libraries which I could use to implement the presented behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is one (disclaimer: author here)

[cropimage-xamarin](https://github.com/markuspalme/cropimage-xamarin)

Comment: I tried it and it's working with great flexibility on resizing. But after testing it, I noticed that it crash the app when the crop size is equal or greater than the initial rectangle size. I don't know why. But to clear out, it is working perfectly if you resize the crop area small than the initial size. Could it be because of total size that extras can't handle it (Just a guess for now) or because of something else?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it to find out where exactly it is crashing? I haven't looked at it for a long time but think we should prevent selecting a larger area than the original image.

Comment: Well I didn't investigate deeply but I had a workaround. I noticed that if sum of width + height is greater than 1000 then it will crash. I tried so many combination to confirm this assumption from 100x900 upto 900x100 and only those sum are greater than 1000 crashed. I just made another method where if sum is greater than 1000, i'll decrease the higher dimension by 1 until it reach the 1000. E.G. 823x432, decrease it until  568x432. And another is if given is 962x678, decrease it till 500x500. Then it's perfectly working now :)